# Incorrect version of form appearance on resize

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

**Issue Details**

When I resize the browser, it displays like this...

[I am sorry, Can't show the image due to low reputation points.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnjhB.png)

Further, when I decrease the browser size, it displays like this...

[I am sorry, Can't show the image due to low reputation points.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aliP.png)

## **[My JS Fiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/afLbrk4t/)**

Am I missing anything in below code?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">  
            <main class="py-4">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header">Login</div>
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <form role="form" class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="Email Address" class="control-label">UserName Or EmailAddress</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="Email Address" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="Password" class="control-label">Password</label>
                                                <input type="password" name="Password" class="form-control">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >
                                                    Login
                                                </button>
                                                <a class="btn btn-link" title="Forgot Password">Forgot Password</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the problem here? If you want a card bigger you have to work on col-md-4 breakpoint, changing the numer or breakpoint name. Your code works well: when you arrive to md-breakpoint, your card becomes from 12 to 4 col, so
it's smaller on desktops than on phones.

Comment: Kindly check first image. In that,  why the card is using very less width? Now check the second image. Why the card is using full width?

Comment: Yes, sure. That's the correct work of col-md-4: when you arrive to md breakpoint its width becomes from 12 to 4 col :)